# What is the difference between Cloud Foundry, PCF Dev, PCF Enterprice, PCF and Pivotal Web services?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services, pcfdev

Please explain what is the difference between CF, PCF, PCF Dev, PCF Enterprise and Pivotal Web services?
Can PCF be installed in our local Workstation and access all the services?

Answer (score 6):

CF - Cloud Foundry is an Open Source project.  It's produced by the Cloud Foundry Foundation, see [here](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/).  Anyone can take the opensource bits and run them. They are free as in freedom and free as in beer.

PCF - [Pivotal Cloud Foundry](https://pivotal.io/platform) is a commercial version of Cloud Foundry that is produced by Pivotal.  It has commercial features that are added over and above what is available in the open source version of Cloud Foundry, but is 100% compatible with Cloud Foundry.  This is a paid offering.

PCF Dev - [PCF Dev](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcfdev/) is a slimmed down version of PCF that you can run on your local machine in a VM.  It has features targeted towards developers that want to work locally or possibly offline.  It does not have all of the features of PCF.  It is free as in beer, but there are commercial components mixed in.  If you need a free as in freedom version, that's possible but you have to [build it yourself](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev#open-source).

PCF Enterprise - I'm not sure what you're referring to here.  If you can clarify where you saw this, I can problem explain it as well.

Pivotal Web services - This is a hosted version of Cloud Foundry by Pivotal.  The core runs the latest open source bits (see CF above) but Pivotal also mixes in some of the PCF service offerings.  Anyone can use PWS, by simply [signing up for an account](https://run.pivotal.io/) and entering a credit card.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. In order to install PCF in our workstation, how many instances of VMs are required?

Comment: I believe PCF Dev is just one VM.

Comment: Inorder to use PCF within an organization for a project, which is the best one that i can use? Is it PCF Dev, or PWS or PCF or CF. Please suggest

Comment: It depends on your organization.  PCF Dev & PWS have a low barrier to entry.  The former you can download and run on your machine and the latter just requires a credit card.  CF & PCF are likely going to require more company buy-in because the resources to run them are higher.  You need at least a small vSphere cluster, or a modest AWS/GCP/Azure budget to get them going.

Comment: Can I avail all the services in PCF Dev and PWS?? Is it for free?

Comment: PCF Dev has some services, but not as many as PWS.  With PCF Dev, I believe you get MySQL, Redis, RabbitMQ & Spring Cloud Services.  That's only if you use the binary version from Pivotal Networks.  The OSS bits don't have those services.  That said, services are only a convenience.  You can create user-provided services and use external services that you manage, maybe a service you spin up with docker also on your local machine.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. If I have to start learning PCF, what are the concepts I should know and how should I get started